# Type of .NET control after custom based serialization?

Tags: winforms, serialization, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, controls

In the process of serializing .NET control objects to custom objects (i.e. MyControlObject) to another process for some purpose, I need to re-draw these controls in a custom manner. I need to know what type it is (button, textbox, combo box, TextField, Calander, ToolStrip, TtoolstripMenu, RichTextBox, TabControl or TreeView). I might need a sort of `typeOf(RichTextBox) == RichTextBox` to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep:

```
if (sayMyControlObject.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
```

or

```
if (sayMyControlObject is TextBox)
```

will do it, but depending on what you do with each it will probably be nicer to encapsulate that into a switch statement like so:

```
switch (config.GetType().Name)
{
      case "TextBox":

      break;

      case "ComboBox":

      break;

      //etc...
}
```

Comment: actually I have serialized "Control" whole object into say some custom object ( CustomControl) and bit by bit  transformed and shifted the data to "CustomControl" object. So this has not the function available "GetType", it is just having all those properties which are inside System.Forms.Control has.

Comment: It should do if it's inherited from "Control", and it's not a property its a method

Comment: If i will inherit it from control, it will through an exception "System.Forms.Controls" cannot be made serializeable...
So i did'nt inherited it, i think i need some custom logic, say some object inside MyCustomControl which will tell that what kind of control it is when it has been serialized to some other process

Comment: I think i have string inside object which will tell me the name of object, and i will use this string as comparison

Comment: All objects should have a GetType method though, how have you managed to hide it?! If not you will need a way of finding it's type, ie. with a string like you have suggested

Comment: yeah Thanks for suggestions. I will preserve the name inside Serializable customControl object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Control c = yourControl;
Type controlType = yourControl.GetType(); // will give you the type
string controlTypeName = controlType.Name; // will give you the name of the type
```